# Change Array[3] for every item in other array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

**EDIT**
Made a mistake in my question. The let tempArr = splitArr is wrong. This needs to be: tempArr = car. So the awnser of @Prime and @sabbir.alam does the trick!

---

I have a array of values where one value (car[3]) of the array is a string seperated by ", ". I created a new array of those elements (splitArr) with the .split(", ").

Now i want to create n number of arrays and replace car[3] with a item in splitArr. But my outcome is only with the last value of the splitArr.

I tried .map .forEach for-loop. The tempArr inside and outside the .arryafunction or for-loop. But always the same result, while the console.log inside the splitArr.forEach shows every item of the splitArr. Below some visual guidence.

**CODE**

```
const car = [ 
  'BMW',
  'Serie1',
  'Gray',
  'Wheels, Lights, Alarm' ]

const splitArr = car[3].split(", ");
const newArr = [];

splitArr.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item);
  let tempArr = splitArr; // This needs to be: car!
  tempArr[3] = item;
  newArr.push(tempArr);
});

console.log(newArr);
```

**OUTCOME**

```
Wheels
Lights
Alarm
[
  [ 'Wheels', 'Lights', 'Alarm', 'Alarm' ],
  [ 'Wheels', 'Lights', 'Alarm', 'Alarm' ],
  [ 'Wheels', 'Lights', 'Alarm', 'Alarm' ]
]
```

**WANTED OUTCOME**

```
Wheels
Lights
Alarm
[
  [ 'BMW', 'Serie1', 'Gray', 'Wheels' ],
  [ 'BMW', 'Serie1', 'Gray', 'Lights' ],
  [ 'BMW', 'Serie1', 'Gray', 'Alarm' ]
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add the wanted result as data structure.

Comment: @NinaScholz the WANTEND OUTCOME you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason that your code doesn't work is that you don't understand the correct way to clone array in JavaScript. You can get more details here.
https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array/

```js
const car = [ 
    'BMW',
    'Serie1',
    'Gray',
    'Wheels, Lights, Alarm' ]
  
  const splitArr = car[3].split(", ");
  const newArr = [];
  
  splitArr.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item);
    let tempArr = [...splitArr]; // <----------------------------------
    tempArr[3] = item;
    newArr.push(tempArr);
  });
  
  console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you keep adding the same array (`splitArr`) and modifying it. You need to make a deep copy every time instead:

```
  ...
  let tempArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(splitArr));
  tempArr.push(item);
  ...
```

Note that using `push` is safer in the sense that you will notice if you are making the above mistake, because the array will keep growing rather than being changed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `map()` would be a good strategy. For each iteration return the array that is looped over with the current item in a new array.

```js
const car = [ 
  'BMW',
  'Serie1',
  'Gray',
  'Wheels, Lights, Alarm' 
];

const splitArr = car[3].split(", ");
const result = splitArr.map((item, i, arr) => [...arr, item]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the temp array like this `let tempArr = [...splitArr]`. When you directly assign the splitArray you are referencing the same array. So any update on tempArray reflects on splitArray.